# Navigation Buttons Centered with main logo

Tags: joomla-3.x, css, jhtml

Hello I have done my best to center my navigation buttons but it still doesn't center it perfectly underneath the main logo. Can anyone help me? Might be missing a line of code or have the wrong values set.

```
.nav-pills > li > a {
padding-right: 12px;
padding-left: 12px;
margin-right: 60px;
line-height: 14px;
}

.nav-pills > li > a {
padding-top: 8px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
margin-top: 2px;
margin-bottom: 2px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
color: white;
background-color: #F6861F;
}

.header .nav-pills > li > a {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.nav-pills > li > a {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.nav-pills > li > a {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

Help would be much appreciated. My page is at,

http://www.webbmaster.com.au/web-programs/questdesign/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.navigation .nav-pills {
    /* add: */
    text-align: center;
 }
.nav-tabs > li, .nav-pills > li{
    /* float: left; */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

and change the padding and margin on

```
.nav-tabs > li > a, .nav-pills > li > a{
   /* ... */
}
```